# Color code for women

Tags: quran, women

Assalamu alaikum
I see a lot of people say women should wear black clothes what is the ruling on this or it’s just a personal idea and it is not mentioned in the quran

Comment: It isn't mentioned in the qur'an for certain, what you wear from the view point of Islam is totally irrelevant as long as it doesn't display what is not allowed to display. One point I often read is that you should also stick to local customs for example if outside the house all women wear black, you shouldn't wear something colorful because it might attire unnecessary attention.